# Obtener arreglo dentro de JSON

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, jsonobject, jsonarray

Quiero obtener un dato dentro de un arreglo dentro de un archivo JSON, este es el ejemplo

```
    {
    "responses": [
    {
      "action": "",
      "affectedContexts": [
        {
          "name": "Bienvenida",
          "lifespan": 5
        }
      ],
      "parameters": [],
      "defaultResponsePlatforms": {},
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": "message",
          "condition": "",
          "speech": [
            "Buenos dias"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "resetContexts": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Quiero obtener el valor de `speech` y he capturado el JSON en la variable `obj`.

He querido obtener el valor por medio de `var speech = obj.responses.messages.speech`, pero cuando lo imprimo en consola, me dice que no se puede leer la propiedad.

Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: dentro de responses tienes un array que contiene a todo lo demás, para acceder a eso deberias tener obj.responses[0].messages.speech, luego en messages tambien tienes otro array para lo cual obj.responses[0].messages[0].speech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estás bien encaminado pero al ser todos arreglos tienes que poner la posición del mismo.

```
speech = obj.responses[0].messages[0].speech[0]
```

Es raro que sean tanto objetos adentro de arreglos, y que esa sólo un objeto por arreglo.
Estas creando por ti mismo el objeto? O te lo devuelve alguna API?
Lo ideal sería que no sean tantos arreglos con un sólo objeto adentro, y sólo ser objetos dentro de objetos. Ahí si podrias acceder a los mismos sin la posición.

```
speech = obj.responses.messages.speech
```

Pero sólo si no tienes arreglos , si sólo son objetos.

Saludos

Comment: Hola, tiene muchos arreglos dentro del JSON, porque es un intento definido en dialogflow y me permite la opcion de descargar en json y este es el ejemplo, estoy construyendo un chatbot y me falta tener una logica de conversacion bien definida, por ello pienso utilizar estos JSOn definidos en dialogflow, si tienes otra idea, espero puedas ayudarme